# how to change id of table cell using javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

I have tried this, but not working.

```
tbl1.rows[0].cells[0].id ='myId';
```

and this is also not working

```
tbl1.rows[0].cells[0].setAttribute("id","newid");
```

how can I do this?

**EDIT:** When view the page source the id is not changed, but when we check using Firebug, then there is shown new Id.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. If it isn't then there might be an error somewhere else or the selector is not the correct one.

See a **[working demo](http://jsbin.com/emiki)**.

***Edit***

Just found that this doesn't work in firefox.

Try

```
document.getElementById("tbl1").rows[0].cells[0].id = "myId";
```

Comment: have you check your link in Firefox?

Comment: Also can you view source after changing, you will not see there? however if click on get, it will return the change id

Comment: View Source shows you the original, not the current state of the source.

Comment: still no success, plz check at your end.

Comment: The example still uses `tbl1` as a global variable, which is a wrongness that only works on IE. The version with `document.getElementById` works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `tbl1.rows[0].cells[0]` is defined? Because if it is a valid DOM element, then simply setting the `id` property should be enough.

Comment: yes, I am access this alert(tbl1.rows[0].cells[0].className);

Answer (score 0):

If tbl1 points to an existing table DOM element then this should work. Are you waiting for the page to load before assigning to tbl1? Perhaps tbl1 is not getting assigned as intended.